# Can't bring up LCD with sunxi-de2 driver in U-boot

Tags: bootloader, u-boot, device-tree, lcd

I have board based on Allwinner's T113-S3 SoC with parallel RGB LCD connected to it. I use U-boot to load Linux basing on Armbian framework. After Linux boots, it is correctly picked up and initialized by OS, so that I can see console on LCD. But I wanted also to show something during bootloader stage, so I tried U-boot's `sunxi_display` driver only to find out it's probably too outdated for my SoC. Then I found out about `sunxi-de2` driver which seems to need just a few registers access adjustments to work. But I can't really test it, because `sunxi-de2` driver seems not to be probed at all during boot. While I was trying `sunxi-display` it didn't work, but at least it was probed and vidconsole was created correctly (nothing was shown on LCD though, obviously). Now I don't get vidconsole to be created at all. I also enabled `simple-panel` and added its node do DTS, and it looks like it's detected and bound properly:

```
bind node panel
- attempt to match compatible string 'qiaodian,qd43003c0-40'
- attempt to match compatible string 'simple-panel'
- found match at 'simple_panel': 'simple-panel' matches 'simple-panel'
```

but it also shows as not probed after all.

```
=>  dm t
 Class     Index  Probed  Driver                Name
-----------------------------------------------------------
 root          0  [ + ]   root_driver           root_driver
 video         0  [   ]   sunxi_de2             |-- sunxi_de2
 clk           0  [ + ]   fixed_clock           |-- dcxo-clk
 simple_bus    0  [ + ]   simple_bus            |-- soc
 pinctrl       0  [ + ]   sunxi-pinctrl         |   |-- pinctrl@2000000
 gpio          0  [ + ]   gpio_sunxi            |   |   |-- pinctrl@2000000
 gpio          1  [   ]   gpio_sunxi            |   |   |   |-- PA
 gpio          2  [   ]   gpio_sunxi            |   |   |   |-- PB
 gpio          3  [   ]   gpio_sunxi            |   |   |   |-- PC
 gpio          4  [   ]   gpio_sunxi            |   |   |   |-- PD
 gpio          5  [   ]   gpio_sunxi            |   |   |   |-- PE
 gpio          6  [ + ]   gpio_sunxi            |   |   |   |-- PF
 gpio          7  [   ]   gpio_sunxi            |   |   |   `-- PG
 pinconfig     0  [   ]   pinconfig             |   |   |-- lcd-rgb666-pins
 pinconfig     1  [ + ]   pinconfig             |   |   |-- mmc0-pins
 pinconfig     2  [ + ]   pinconfig             |   |   |-- mmc1-pins
 pinconfig     3  [ + ]   pinconfig             |   |   |-- uart3-pb-pins
 pinconfig     4  [   ]   pinconfig             |   |   `-- pwm7-pin
 clk           1  [ + ]   sunxi_clk             |   |-- clock-controller@2001000
 reset         0  [ + ]   sunxi_reset           |   |   `-- reset
 serial        0  [ + ]   ns16550_serial        |   |-- serial@2500c00
 mmc           0  [ + ]   sunxi_mmc             |   |-- mmc@4020000
 blk           0  [ + ]   mmc_blk               |   |   |-- mmc@4020000.blk
 partition     0  [ + ]   blk_partition         |   |   |   `-- mmc@4020000.blk:1
 bootdev       0  [   ]   mmc_bootdev           |   |   `-- mmc@4020000.bootdev
 mmc           1  [ + ]   sunxi_mmc             |   |-- mmc@4021000
 blk           1  [   ]   mmc_blk               |   |   |-- mmc@4021000.blk
 bootdev       1  [   ]   mmc_bootdev           |   |   `-- mmc@4021000.bootdev
 clk           2  [ + ]   clk_sun6i_rtc         |   `-- rtc@7090000
 regulator     0  [   ]   regulator_fixed       |-- regulator-5v
 regulator     1  [ + ]   regulator_fixed       |-- regulator-3v3
 regulator     2  [   ]   regulator_fixed       |-- regulator-core
 regulator     3  [   ]   regulator_fixed       |-- regulator-avdd
 panel         0  [   ]   simple_panel          |-- panel
 bootstd       0  [   ]   bootstd_drv           `-- bootstd
 bootmeth      0  [   ]   bootmeth_efi              |-- efi
 bootmeth      1  [   ]   bootmeth_extlinux         |-- extlinux
 bootmeth      2  [   ]   bootmeth_pxe              |-- pxe
 bootmeth      3  [   ]   vbe_simple                `-- vbe_simple
```

I don't know what I am lacking here. Drivers are bound properly but aren't probed, and thus my LCD is not working. Any ideas?